My Raspberry Pi is making a high-pitch sound. What could be the problem?
My Raspberry Pi was unplugged without proper system shutdown during a stormy night. When I re-plugged it back into the power source, it makes a high-pitch sound. The Pi shows the red light flashing consistently, but the green light is flashing uncontrolably (a.k.a., it flashes many times per second). After some research, I found that my SD-card may be corrupted. I decided to re-format the SD card and reinstall the operating system. After doing so, the same problem persisted. I know that the flashing of green light usually indicates a problem within the boot sector of the Pi. However, the green light did not flash in such a paddern that conforms to any of the possible boot errors (e.g., a flash of three times may suggest that loader.bin cannot be found), thereby making it hard to troubleshoot the problem. What could be the problem of my Pi not booting up?
I have a Raspberry 4B.
Thanks for your time

Your Q intrigued me. I did a search, but found only one other case of reported "squealing".

@Seamus, except my Pi won't boot up.

"The Pi shows the red light flashing consistently" the PWR LED should NOT flash - this indicates inadequate power supply (or damage to PMIC).

@Milliways, how do you know it's the PWR light that is flashing? Isn't that normal for the Pi's red light to flash in a solid state when it is being powered on?

The red LED is PWR - NO it should be solid.

Mmm... no, the PWR LED can be set up to behave as a flashing light - but that's not the default. I know that behavior can be set in config.txt - and it could be something in the firmware that's causing it to behave that way.

If it makes you feel better, you're not the only one who's had the red flashing light... but you may be the only one who's had "squealing" with a light show  :)  I don't mean to make light of your situation...   My best guess would be a power issue - either the power supply, or the PMIC (Pwr Mgt IC) on the Pi 4. Best guess is to try another power source/supply (the wall wart). If that doesn't work, it's something on the board.

@Seamus, the red light is flashing solidly, but the green light is flashing--seems like twice per interval of time frame--somewhat strangely. Is it the SD-card corrupted?

I wish I knew - but I don't. What's happened to your Pi is definitely weird, and probably not due to anything you've done. If it were mine, I'd contact the vendor (or even the Raspberry Pi Organization) about a replacement. Your Pi may be a valuable commodity to an organization that cares about quality! If you can get a replacement, you should try to get the Pwr Supply replaced also (assuming it's an official PS).
